# Is there any kind of "radar" system That can detect electrical fields / electricity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, electricity, electric-fields, radar

I may be using improper terms here, but Is there any kind of "radar" / non-contact system That can detect electrical fields / electricity? see fig for clarification to what I'm talking about.
[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroencephalography and on the sensor you put, say a wifi t/r module instead of wires

Comment: I mean some thing that can be used from afar such as an antenna

Comment: It depends on the material where the "intense electrical activity" is happening. If it's a nonlinear material you might be able to detect it. If it's not nonlinear, you won't be able to detect it. That means a spark (a nonlinear phenomenon that creates a plasma) is probably detectable, but synaptic activity in the brain (really a pretty weak electrical event) probably not.

Comment: For imaging brain activity, you can google "fMRI", which actually detects the increase in blood flow to different regions of the brain when they are active, not the actual electrical activity in the brain.